# jQuery event fire on redirecting?

Tags: jquery, events, redirect

I have several redirects to slow-rendering pages (lots of back-end computations), and I want to give feedback to the user that his/ her machine is actually doing something (planning on using an animated gif in the center of the screen).

Is there an event that I can key on that will let me pop up the gif so the user doesn't keep trying to click the link?  If not, is there a way I can reliably "fake it"?

I tried Googling this but my keywords are too generic, lots of hits about almost completely unrelated stuff, so I figured I'd toss this out here.

**UPDATE**

I should probably be clearer, because I may be lumping terminology together that is not typically put together.  I am considering a redirect to be when someone clicks a menu item to go to another page as well as a header-based redirect.

Comment: Disable the link once clicked.

Comment: Are the redirects required, would an ajax request to load the final state/page (after computations) not be sufficient? That way you could at least show the legendary 'reticulating splines' (or similar) text in the same page; if my browser loaded a page and then flickered through redirects I would close my browser, and never go back (on the assumption of something sinister and, at the very least, irritating happening).

Comment: @DavidThomas well, there's a bunch of pages with a 5-10 second delay, I'm not planning on rearchitecting the site to do everything with AJAX calls.  I just want to acknowledge the user's input and let him/ her know that the system is thinking about it.  It's not a bunch of redirects in a row, it's the page requests that are taking a bit to respond.

Comment: Then communication is your only answer; have the new pages give feedback on what they're doing, or why, or how far they've got. I'd suggest the first page lets the user know that this will take some time, and that they shouldn't worry about it, unless it takes greater than *x* amount of time. You can block UI, obviously, but I know that, especially without warning, that would annoy me profoundly. Whether I then killed the page or not depends on the necessity of using your service.

Comment: If you load a new page, you can't accomplish this : from the moment the http request is sent, you change to a new blank page with no front-end content yet. If you want to keep an event running client-side while waiting the server-side computing to finish, you need to keep a client-side page running your gif (or any loading animation). So Loading your page with AJAX call into an existing page is what I would do.

Comment: @Tiki-Web That doesn't sound right to me... the behavior I am seeing is clicking on a link that takes a while to respond keeps the page on the original, and then when the _response_ begins, the page goes to a new blank page, not when the _request_ begins.

Comment: Yeah you're right, what was I thinking... So what you should do is displaying an overlay with a loading animation, to prevent any other interaction while the page is loading, and asking user to be patient while loading.

Comment: @Tiki-Web yes... that's what I am thinking of doing, but do you know what event I could key off of?

Comment: The click event should be nice. Be sure to select only the concerned links (class, markup) to bind your code.

Comment: @Tiki-Web bleh, I'm hoping there's some other method that would be more universal.  Doing it that way I have to keep track of slow-rendering pages.  I'd rather have that be the default behavior.  With a quick-rendering page, the gif wouldn't even have time to show up.

Comment: Then make it a general behavior ^^

Answer (score 0):

[pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) is a very nifty way of page navigation without actually reloading the page, which will both speed up your load and also let you indicate that something is happening. You can block the UI with [blockUI](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/) to prevent the user from touching anything else - or you can simply "disable" the element that's been clicked when you know it should navigate.